# Как трансформировать блок в трапецию css3

Tags: css3

Читал про трансформацию с помощью матрицы преобразований, но так и не нашел ни живого примера ни нормальной теории, как сделать блок, у которого допустим, верхняя и нижняя стороны были бы равны, а левая была бы короче правой. Если не трудно или есть уже готовое решение, покажите пример кода.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вот прочитайте http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp

Answer (score 1):

в принципе вот рабочий вариант:))

```css
.trapeciya {
  transform: perspective(224px) rotateY(-63deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 80px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapeciya">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности играет важную роль в формировании направлений прогрессивного развития. С другой стороны начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции требуют определения и уточнения
  существенных финансовых и административных условий.
  <div>
```