# Как сверстать срезанные углы?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сверстать вот такую фигуру, но я не знаю как срезать углы. На ум приходит border через after и before с overflow:hidden, но не знаю, как это реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя фигура с фоном:

```css
.title-head {
 width: 358px;
 height: 80px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6c0a6 0%, white 100%, #ff3f00 100%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="title-head">

</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как трансформировать блок в трапецию css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499202/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-css3)

Comment: а где тут срезаны углы? вижу градиент и трансформацию по одной из осей. срезанных углов не вижу

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, срезать углы можно не только трансформациями, так что этот вопрос более общий, чем предлагаемый вами.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Так подойдет?

Только здесь угол другой.

```css
.title-head {
  position: relative;
    width: 358px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6c0a6 0%, white 100%, #ff3f00 100%, white 100%);
}

.title-head:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-left: 80px solid white;
    width: 0;
}
.title-head:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid white;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-head"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS **Transform** приходит на помощь, вот пример:

```css
.title-head {
    transform: perspective(224px) rotateX(-20deg);
    width: 358px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6c0a6 0%, white 100%, #ff3f00 100%, white 100%);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-head"></div>
```

**Если надо, чтобы поверх был текст**, делаем что то вроде:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2% auto;
  width: 358px;
}

.title-head {
  transform: perspective(224px) rotateX(-20deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6c0a6 0%, white 100%, #ff3f00 100%, white 100%);
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5.5% 3%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #5D1600;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text'>Заголовок</div>
  <div class='title-head'></div>
</div>
```